# How to make lines on Grid using canvas in JavaFX?

Tags: java, user-interface, canvas, line

**How to make lines on Grid using canvas in JavaFX?**

How to make lines on Grid using canvas in JavaFX. Where I have a case study as follows:

I have a 10 x 10 grid, where each line will be formed according to the grid point, for example the starting point ([0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [i, j])).

Example output:

[Example Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYKAe.jpg)

Also, I need to work on Canvas.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.